# React Modal - Closing by clicking outside of Modal is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

So far my modal works fine, and does what it's supposed to be.
But when i try to implement a way to let the modal close when i click outside the modal I run into some bugs.

e.g. i tried to add onClick={() => setShowModal(false) in the top div, but then the button to open the modal no longer works, bcs this button is inside the top div with the setShowModal(false) function.

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);


<div className='flex justify-center md:justify-end md:mt-4 mt-12'>
                <button
                  onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
                  className='bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-400 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-red-700 rounded'
                >
                  Delete account button
                </button>
                {showModal && (
                  <>
                    <div className='justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none'>
                      <div className='relative w-auto my-6 mx-auto max-w-3xl'>
                        <div className=' bg-gray-600 rounded-lg shadow-2xl relative flex flex-col w-full bg-white outline-none focus:outline-none'>
                          <div className='flex items-start justify-between p-5 border-b border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-t'>
                            <h3 className='text-3xl font-semibold text-red-500'>
                              Delete account
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                          <div className='relative p-6 flex-auto'>
                            <p className='my-4 text-white text-lg leading-relaxed'>
                              Are you sure...
                            </p>
                          </div>
                          <div className='flex items-center justify-end p-6 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b'>
                            <button
                              className='text-red-500 background-transparent font-bold uppercase px-6 py-2 text-sm outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150'
                              type='button'
                              onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
                            >
                              Cancel
                            </button>
                            <button
                              className='bg-red-500 text-white active:bg-red-600 font-bold uppercase text-sm px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150'
                              type='button'
                              onClick={() => handleSelfDelete(user._id)}
                            >
                              Confirm
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   <div
                      className='w-full h-screen opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-10 bg-black'
                      onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
                    />
                  </>
                )}
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<>
                    <div
                      className='backdrop'
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        if (e.target.className === 'backdrop') {
                          setShowModal(false);
                        }
                        console.log(e);
                      }}
                    >
                      <div className='relative w-auto my-6 mx-auto max-w-3xl'>
                        <div className=' rounded-lg shadow-2xl relative flex flex-col w-full bg-white outline-none focus:outline-none'>
                          <div className='flex items-start justify-between p-5 border-b border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-t bg-gray-600'>
                            <h3 className='text-3xl font-semibold text-red-500'>
                              Account löschen
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                          <div className='relative p-6 flex-auto bg-gray-600'>
                            <p className='my-4 text-white text-lg leading-relaxed'>
                              Bist du dir sicher, dass du deinen Account bei uns
                              löschen möchtest? Solltest du dich dazu
                              entscheiden deinen Account zu löschen, werden wir
                              alle deine accountbezogenen, persönlichen Daten
                              für immer löschen. Es besteht keine Möglichkeit,
                              diesen Schritt rückgängig zu machen.
                            </p>
                          </div>
                          <div className='flex items-center justify-end p-6 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b bg-gray-600'>
                            <button
                              className='text-red-500 background-transparent font-bold uppercase px-6 py-2 text-sm outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150'
                              type='button'
                              onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
                            >
                              Abbrechen
                            </button>
                            <button
                              className='bg-red-500 text-white active:bg-red-600 font-bold uppercase text-sm px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150'
                              type='button'
                              onClick={() => handleSelfDelete(user._id)}
                            >
                              Account löschen
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </>
```

css

```
.backdrop{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    z-index:10; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have a `<div>` adjacent to the modal serving as a backdrop and when you click on it set the modal state to false

```
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);


<div className='flex justify-center md:justify-end md:mt-4 mt-12'>
                <button
                  onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
                  className='bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-400 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-red-700 rounded'
                >
                  Delete account button
                </button>
                {showModal && (
                  <>
                    <div classname='backdrop' onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}/>
                    <div className='justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none'>
                      <div className='relative w-auto my-6 mx-auto max-w-3xl'>
                        <div className=' bg-gray-600 rounded-lg shadow-2xl relative flex flex-col w-full bg-white outline-none focus:outline-none'>
                          <div className='flex items-start justify-between p-5 border-b border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-t'>
                            <h3 className='text-3xl font-semibold text-red-500'>
                              Delete account
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                          <div className='relative p-6 flex-auto'>
                            <p className='my-4 text-white text-lg leading-relaxed'>
                              Are you sure...
                            </p>
                          </div>
                          <div className='flex items-center justify-end p-6 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b'>
                            <button
                              className='text-red-500 background-transparent font-bold uppercase px-6 py-2 text-sm outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150'
                              type='button'
                              onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
                            >
                              Cancel
                            </button>
                            <button
                              className='bg-red-500 text-white active:bg-red-600 font-bold uppercase text-sm px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150'
                              type='button'
                              onClick={() => handleSelfDelete(user._id)}
                            >
                              Confirm
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-black'></div>
                  </>
                )}
              </div>
```

CSS

```
.backdrop{
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100vh;
        z-index:10;  <--has to be lower than your modal z-index
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75)
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, but not working. Maybe it's about the z-index bcs neither the rgba change nor a click does anything.

Comment: @zuzuzuu do you already use your own backdrop maybe? If so, delete mine and do the exact same thing on your backdrop. For example the last div you have with className opacity-25 fixed inset etc seems like a backdrop. If that is the case just add there the onClick

Comment: i edit my post and add to my own backdrop the w-full and h-screen class from tailwind but nothing changed. no opacity in background nor modal would close on outside click

Comment: Try @Marios code but remove the fragment (<></>) on the outside of the modal & wrap your current modal with the added div, and you'll have to adjust accordingly

Comment: @Amanda that's the best so far. the opacity is there now, but where ever   i click (including the modal itself) it closes the modal

Comment: @zuzuzuu I think you should keep the <></> because the backdrop HAS to be sidebyside with the modal and not enclosing it , that's why now when you click the modal also closes, because it is essentially inside the backdrop. Keep it as before but with only one backdrop div, remove the one from tailwind. I can't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: I've added a fix to my answer that should solve the issue with clicking within the modal. You don't need a fragment if the modal itself is inside a div, but if it works, it works.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this should work for the setup of your divs while removing the fragment

```
show modal && 
<div classname="backdrop" onclick=(()=>setShowModal(false))>
<div classname="modal" onclick=((e)=>{e.stopPropagation()})>
...stuff in modal...
</div> //modal
</div> //backdrop
```

Comment: Amanda this way the modal is inside the backdrop therefore even clicking anywhere inside the modal will close it and that's not what we want :(

Comment: I forgot to add a line, I edited it in! It should work now! @Marios

Answer (score 0):

curly brackets for the shouldCloseOnClickOutside false works for me with react

```
<Modal
 title={__('my modal', 'xxx')}
 shouldCloseOnClickOutside={false}
 shouldCloseOnEsc={true}
>
enter code here
</Modal>
```